# MongoError: failed to connect to server using docker-compose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

Here's my docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    image: chaseloyd/portfolio-site:latest
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
  mongo2:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongo2
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "27018:27018"
  game:
    image: chaseloyd/multiplayer-game:latest
    ports:
      - "3030:3030"
    links:
      - "mongo2"
```

here's my code:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect("mongodb://mongo2:27018/db");
```

the error:

```
MongoError: failed to connect to server [mongo2:27018] on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.19.0.3:27018]
```

I was expecting it would connect successfully. This container worked at some point. I'm trying to re-create the docker-compose file that tied these containers together successfully. Thank you for your time. You can try on your machine quite easily.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks bot but this small amount of code can reproduce the whole project and it's error. I'd like the compose file to be fixed. This is a straight-forward question so don't worry about us.

Answer (score 0):

To let Docker containers communicate with each other by name, a docker `network` should be created. Here in this case, containers `app`, `mongo2`, and if necessary,`game` should stay on the same network for them to communicate with each other. You can create a network like this,

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    image: chaseloyd/portfolio-site:latest
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - test-network

  mongo2:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongo2
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "27018:27018"
    networks:
      - test-network

  game:
    image: chaseloyd/multiplayer-game:latest
    ports:
      - "3030:3030"
    links:
      - "mongo2"
    networks:
      - test-network
networks:
  test-network:
```

Comment: This still produces the same "failed to connect to server" error